# How can I develop a system to translate ideas into Ideograms?

Tags: icon, workflow, information-graphics, visualization, information-design

I am in the process of creating some infographics for some design thinking methods. I need to translate sometimes [**complex (but with common themes) ideas**](http://www.designmethodsandprocesses.co.uk) into visuals.

To put it a different way, why does it, when you see an arrow pointing right, indicate that you should go or look right?

Comment: I have mentioned this elsewhere, but there is an entire scientific field dedicated to this: semiotics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics  i might give a run-down here, but it will take some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

1. **Use cultural conventions and associations**. There are millions, humans soak up conventions. The shape of arrows are a convention, as are [warning signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_symbol), ['save disks'](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/), etc. Spot and use them.
2. **Consider [affordances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance)**: if something looks like X can be done with it, looking at it brings to mind X.
3. **Make sure [the symbolism goes the right way](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15781/)**. It's never "What imagery comes to mind *while* I'm thinking about X?", it's "What imagery *brings* X to mind?". Very different (much harder!).
4. **Simplify the image**. A good exercise I was taught is start with a 16 x 16 grid: any deviation from those grid lines beyond connecting grid corners with straight lines or curves must be *essential*.
5. **Test it**. Show people, ask them to talk about what they see and what they think of (no clues!)
6. **Test it again**. You could mix up symbols and labels to see how easily people can match them up.
7. **Test some more**.

Longer answer: the design of signs, symbols and pictograms is a whole field of study in its own right. Some starting points...

- There's [some good historical background here (esp re Otto Neurath and Gerd Arntz)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15684/3327)
- The book [Pictograms, icons & signs: a guide to information graphics](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Pictograms_icons_signs.html?id=ui1QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) is worth a look.
- [Visual Language for Designers](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Visual_Language_for_Designers.html?id=S_jOuc-GBfQC&redir_esc=y) and [Design For Information](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HR_7AAAAQBAJ&dq=design%20for%20information&source=gbs_book_other_versions) are also good for more general information design principles.
- [Universal Methods of Design](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Universal_Methods_of_Design.html?id=uZ8uzWAcdxEC&redir_esc=y) probably has some relevant workflow suggestions (I don't have it to hand to check right now though).
- As Boblet mentions the field of [semiotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics) is related. It's more academic: more about analysing symbolism and theorising than *using* symbolism, but worth a look if you get very interested.

Comment: Wow! May I add: use the principles of physics. Gravity is always pointed downwards, so in flow-charts, the logical flow of things would be from the top downward. For an arrow: if something moves, anything attached to it wil —because of drag—, lag behind. Imagine a spear with ribbons: it would atomatically take the shape of an arrow. It's even stronger then cultural convention.